# Create a subset containing '0' as records

Tags: r, subset, zero, leading-zero

I have a dataframe whose one field contains different numbers. However, it also contains some 0/000/00000000. How can I identify in a given dataset all the values containing 0,00,000,0000,00000 and so on until 0000000000 and display all those records? Using OR logical operator for all the combinations seems tedious. Is there any other workaround?

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regular expressions. I assume it is a character vector.

```
grep("^0+$", df$col)
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating example data:

```
set.seed(100)
library('data.table')
nums <- sample(c(11101, 11001, 10001, 99991, 99992, 99993), 52, T)
DT <- data.table(A = LETTERS, B = nums)
```

Using data.table:

```
DT[, B := as.character(B)]
subDT <- DT[B %like% '0']
```

Using data.frame and data.table:

```
setDF(DT)
subDT <- DT[like(DT$B, '0'),]
```

Using data.frame and dplyr:

```
library('dplyr')
subDT <- DT %>%
  filter(grepl('0', B, T))
```

Using data.frame and stringi:

```
library('stringi')
subDT <- DT[stri_detect_fixed(DT$B, '0'),]
# if you're only interested in leading 0's
subDT <- DT[stri_detect_regex(DT$B, '^0+'),]
```